# Python how to minus a string from a list of string?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.x

I am doing a mini project and i have encountered the problem suggested in title. Below is a example:

```
list = ["bird", "deer", "dog", "bat"]
list -= "bird"
print list
```

and the error says:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'str'

This seemed like an omnipresent questions so i searched it up but couldn't found the relevant answer, very sorry if this question is repeative to others on this site. Help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list.remove()`

For example:

```
example_lst = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 'xyz']; 
example_lst.remove('xyz');
print "List : ", example_lst
example_lst.remove('abc');
print "List : ", example_lst
```

Output:

```
List :  [123, 'zara', 'abc', 'xyz']
List :  [123, 'zara', 'xyz']
```

The example above is taken from [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_remove.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use remove:

```
list.remove("bird")
```